# How can I prevent a Netsuite custom field formula from displaying an error caused by a (temporarily) missing field?

Tags: formula, customization, netsuite

I want to display the quantity remaining (qty ordered less qty fulfilled) on the lines of a sales order.  I'm using the suggestion here:

http://www.netsuiterp.com/2018/09/add-quantity-remaining-column-on-sales.html

with a small tweak of the formula to exclude closed lines (case when {isclosed} <> 'T' then {quantity}-{quantityfulfilled} else 0 end).

The problem I'm having is that though it works perfectly for sales orders once they've been saved, when a user is creating a new sales order this field displays an error apparently because one of the fields referenced in my formula doesn't exist yet for that transaction.  Usually it is "ERROR: Field 'quantityfulfilled' Not Found".  I've tried adding some null-value handling to my formula, like adding

and nvl({quantityfulfilled},'') <> ''

to the 'when' condition, but I'm guessing the absence of the field is different from a null value since the error is unaffected.  This is distracting and confusing to users.  Is there a way to prevent it from displaying?

Answer (score 0):

in scripts checking on internal id can be used as a test for a new record so:

```sql
case when {internalid} is null then 0 when {isclosed} = 'T' then 0 else {quantity}-{quantityfulfilled} end
```

Comment: I felt sure this would work, but I used your formula exactly and the result was "ERROR: Field 'internalid' Not Found".  I tried checking for some other nulls as well, but it seems like the problem is including any field not on the list of available fields in the formula dialog.